# Is it possible to make a multiple-collection index (or search) in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, full-text-search, mongodb-query

I have an app that queries a MongoDB database with a text index that has to return objects from multiple collections, just like the Instagram query that looks for people, hashtags or locations at the same time.

I'm looking for a way to have this collections separated normally, but having a single MongoDB index for the 3 collections.

I've been looking for this but all I find is multiple column indexes and compound indexes inside the same collection.

Is this possible to accomplish on MongoDB? Without making another collection to store all objects, I mean...

If not, can I query multiple collections using similar indexes like full-text and geolocated indexes?

Comment: Is it possible to make a multiple-collection index in MongoDB? -> **No**

Comment: Why would you want to separate the collection ? If the use case is to query them all together?

Comment: @WanBachtiar They are different objects. The "query-all" objects functionality I wanted to use on Mongo is the same use case that is common in a Lucene index, you query the whole text index, and then you discover which collection it belongs...

Comment: A while later although I think the problem remains. I'm comparing the usage of neo4j and MongoDB (preferred option on the project) and I got exactly there. The Lucene ability to index multiple kind of nodes vs an index for each collection representing different kind of nodes while my search will have to go through all the nodes/documents... So Neo4J wins here!

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't provide inter collection communication mostly to maintain high availability and scaling ability. ($lookup is one off exception).

So index spanning different collection? NO, joins on different collection, NO (at least No for healthy use). Triggers? NO (Not yet). Transactions? NO.

It would be a mess if mongoDB is used with RDBMS best practices. learn to denormalize.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. What I'm asking has nothing to do with RDBMS best practices... More like a Lucene/Solr best practice (also applies to other full-text search engines), I want to index text from different objects and query them all, and after that I can distinguish which type they are...

Comment: I have similar requirement @ViniciusPires , did you get how to achieve it?